# Django: Load fixture fails if new field is created in model while running test cases, causing to fail build

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

My Django app have existing migration files with fixture loading as well. Later created a new field 'New_field' with its migration file dependent on load fixture migration file, now every time it try to run test cases it fails with error saying no such column New_field ('New_field' is my new field created when I already had a load fixture migration )

Error:
OperationalError: Problem installing fixture 'initial_data.yaml': Could not load config.TestClass(pk=1): no such column: New_field